# NPM Install failing in theme based on old version of Understrap Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, npm, sass, gulp

I'm trying to do some basic styling updates to a Wordpress theme that uses a theme based on an old version of Understrap. The issue is that I am falling at the first hurdle: I cannot even run npm install: I think this is because the theme is using a fairly old version of Understrap Child (0.5.2) from when Understrap still used Gulp. I am getting the error message below. I know v little about NPM or Gulp (I've used Understrap and NPM before, but not so old a copy) so I'm not sure how to proceed – if I need to use an old version of npm/gulp/sass to get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
8388 error code 1
8389 error path C:\Users\georg\Desktop\clean\node_modules\node-sass
8390 error command failed
8391 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Temp\postinstall-a4c0f0fb.cmd
8392 error Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\georg\Desktop\clean\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
8393 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
8393 error gyp verb cli [
8393 error gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
8393 error gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\georg\\Desktop\\clean\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
8393 error gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
8393 error gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
8393 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
8393 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
8393 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
8393 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
8393 error gyp verb cli ]
8393 error gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
8393 error gyp info using node@16.17.0 | win32 | x64
8393 error gyp verb command rebuild []
8393 error gyp verb command clean []
8393 error gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
8393 error gyp verb command configure []
8393 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\georg\Desktop\clean\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\georg\Desktop\clean\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\georg\Desktop\clean\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\georg\Desktop\clean\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\georg\Desktop\clean\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\georg\Desktop\clean\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:206:21)
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\georg\Desktop\clean\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\georg\Desktop\clean\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\georg\Desktop\clean\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\georg\Desktop\clean\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\georg\Desktop\clean\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\georg\Desktop\clean\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:206:21) {
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
8393 error gyp verb `which` failed }
8393 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
8393 error gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python310\python.EXE
8393 error gyp ERR! configure error 
8393 error gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python310\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
8393 error gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
8393 error gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
8393 error gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
8393 error gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
8393 error gyp ERR! stack 
8393 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:400:12)
8393 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
8393 error gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
8393 error gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
8393 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
8393 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\georg\\Desktop\\clean\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
8393 error gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\georg\Desktop\clean\node_modules\node-sass
8393 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.0
8393 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
8393 error gyp ERR! not ok 
8393 error Build failed with error code: 1
8394 verbose exit 1
8395 timing npm Completed in 72165ms
8396 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1667584022337
8397 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1667584072573
8398 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1667584072576
8399 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1667584072576
8400 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall 1667584073408
8401 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall:node_modules/node-sass 1667584073454
8402 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall:node_modules/understrap 1667584073486
8403 verbose code 1
```

Comment: Try installing an older version of [node using NVM.](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). And try your build process again.

Comment: @disinfor I had tried that before I posted to no success but I just went back after your comment and tried an even older version (node 10.11.0) and ran it in administrator and it worked perfectly, thanks so much!